# Multiple AJAX requests using when

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

One AJAX Request works but when I add a second one it doesn't.

Working code (returns 'wins: 3' as expected)

```js
function GetMissingData(data, myID)
{
 $.when(AJAXf1(myID, '4')).done(
  function(a1)
  {
   console.log("wins: "+a1[0].DATA);
  }
 );
  }

function AJAXf1(myID, val)
{
 return $.ajax({   
  url: "./PHP/ajaxRequests.php",   
  dataType: "json",
  data : 
   {
    'moreData' : myID,
    'res' : val
   }
 })
}
```

and this doesn't, variable is now undefined ('wins: undefined'):

```js
function GetMissingData(data, myID)
{
 
 $.when(AJAXf1(myID, '4'), AJAXf1(myID, '4')).done(
  function(a1, a2)
  {
   console.log("wins: "+a1[0].DATA);
  }
 );
}

function AJAXf1(myID, val)
{
 return $.ajax({   
  url: "./PHP/ajaxRequests.php",   
  dataType: "json",
  data : 
   {
    'moreData' : myID,
    'res' : val
   }
 })
}
```

(yes, I'm calling same function, I was testing. In the future, I will change one of the parameters of the function)

Thanks

Comment: You have a spelling of `AJAXf1` in one place and `AJAXF1` in another place.

Comment: That just happened when simplifying the name of functions/vars, will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you got an ajax response directly as a single JS object.
In the second one you got an array of JS objects (something like *[Object, "success", Object]*). And I think you just can't use the same code on different structures.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. Good answers are specific and based on fact rather than opinion. Try describing exactly why the same code doesn't work on different structures in this case.

Comment: Correct, it's working now. To access the var it has to be done this way: a1[0][0].DATA Thank you very much. I mark your answer as correct!